# Problem with ``tikzpicture`` in beamer in creating a matrix

Tags: beamer, pdftex, tikz-styles

I'm trying to use tikz in beamer as follows but get an error "Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}"

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\usepackage{lipsum, ragged2e, etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
%\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{dsfont, color, soul, tikz, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, graphicx, arydshln, fixmath, mathtools, multirow, boldline, xcolor, colortbl, url, algorithm, algpseudocode, subfig, media9, hyperref, blindtext, import, tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds}

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{2ex}}
\makeatletter
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 2pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette quaternary}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \vskip-9ex%
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}{}
%       \hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}%
%       \insertslidenavigationsymbol
%       \insertframenavigationsymbol
%       \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
%       \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
%       \insertdocnavigationsymbol
%       \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
%   \end{beamercolorbox}%    
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3ex,dp=4ex]{section in head/foot}%
%       \insertnavigation{.9\paperwidth}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \insertnavigation{.9\paperwidth}
%       \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}%
\makeatother

%\AtBeginSection[]{
%   \begin{frame}
%   \vfill
%   \centering
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
%       \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
%   \end{beamercolorbox}
%   \vfill
%\end{frame}
%}

%\makeatother
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}
%{
%   \leavevmode%
%   \hbox{%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
%           \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{}
%       \end{beamercolorbox}%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
%           \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{}
%       \end{beamercolorbox}%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
%           \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}}%
%   \vskip0pt%
%}
%\makeatletter

\title{My title}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
%\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{Me}
% - Give the names in the same order as the appear in the paper.
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.

\institute[University] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  %\inst{1}%
  Electrical and Computer Engineering Department\\
  \vspace{.3cm}
  }


\date{October 1, 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
\lambda_{\max}(W_c) = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
matrix of math nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
minimum width=width("998888"),
] {
    1.5678 & 9.1645 & 5.2552 & 3.6413\\
    4.3001 & 1.5605 & 5.2552 & 3.6413\\
    6.0162 & 4.0937 & 1.5561 & 3.6413\\
    10.0278 & 5.6221 & 3.8836 & 1.5504\\
};
\draw (m-2-1.south west) rectangle (m-2-4.north east);
\draw (m-1-3.north west) rectangle (m-4-3.south east);
\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node[fill=gray!30, fit=(m-2-3)(m-2-3) ]   {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\matrix [ampersand replacement=\&,...]` and replace all `&` by `\&`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. Also how can I resize it? Using \scalebox{0.75}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} \end{minipage}} around it produces error.

Comment: You have to put that inside the `frame` environment.

Comment: It is already in the ``frame`` environment!

Comment: I see, then you just have to put it in the right place.  Try putting it around `equation`.

Comment: Done! (ampersand replacement worked).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112497/discussion-between-mohammad-and-henri-menke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `fragile` to your frames with `tikzpicture`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\usepackage{lipsum, ragged2e, etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % include this line if your document contains figures
%\usepackage{natbib}        % required for bibliography
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{dsfont, color, soul, tikz, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, graphicx, arydshln, fixmath, mathtools, multirow, boldline, xcolor, colortbl, url, algorithm, algpseudocode, subfig, media9, hyperref, blindtext, import, tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds}

\addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{2ex}}
\makeatletter
\def\hrulefill{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 2pt\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
    \endgroup
}
    
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette quaternary}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \vskip-9ex%
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}{}
%       \hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}%
%       \insertslidenavigationsymbol
%       \insertframenavigationsymbol
%       \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
%       \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
%       \insertdocnavigationsymbol
%       \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
%   \end{beamercolorbox}%    
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=3ex,dp=4ex]{section in head/foot}%
%       \insertnavigation{.9\paperwidth}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \insertnavigation{.9\paperwidth}
%       \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%
}%
\makeatother

%\AtBeginSection[]{
%   \begin{frame}
%   \vfill
%   \centering
%   \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
%       \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
%   \end{beamercolorbox}
%   \vfill
%\end{frame}
%}

%\makeatother
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}
%{
%   \leavevmode%
%   \hbox{%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
%           \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}{}
%       \end{beamercolorbox}%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
%           \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{}
%       \end{beamercolorbox}%
%       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
%           \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{1ex}
%   \end{beamercolorbox}}%
%   \vskip0pt%
%}
%\makeatletter

\title{My title}

% A subtitle is optional and this may be deleted
%\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{Me}
% - Give the names in the same order as the appear in the paper.
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.

\institute[University] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  %\inst{1}%
  Electrical and Computer Engineering Department\\
  \vspace{.3cm}
  }


\date{October 1, 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile] %<--- Add fragile here
  \begin{equation}
\lambda_{\max}(W_c) = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [
matrix of math nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
minimum width=width("998888"),
] {
    1.5678 & 9.1645 & 5.2552 & 3.6413\\
    4.3001 & 1.5605 & 5.2552 & 3.6413\\
    6.0162 & 4.0937 & 1.5561 & 3.6413\\
    10.0278 & 5.6221 & 3.8836 & 1.5504\\
};
\draw (m-2-1.south west) rectangle (m-2-4.north east);
\draw (m-1-3.north west) rectangle (m-4-3.south east);
\scoped[on background layer]
{
    \node[fill=gray!30, fit=(m-2-3)(m-2-3) ]   {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]